# Opening editable inline textarea with one element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click `edit` opens editable`textarea` for all elements. How to set it so that it opens only at the element that I clicked.

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yoevt8

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      showTextAreaEdit: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodos();
  }

  displayEdit = () => {
    this.setState({
      showTextAreaEdit: true
    })
  }

  getTodos = () => {
    axios({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
      method: 'GET'    
    })
      .then(res => {    
        this.setState({
          todos: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
          return (<li key={todo.id}>
              {this.state.showTextAreaEdit ?
                <span>
                  <textarea>{todo.title}</textarea>
                  <button>Save</button>
                </span> 
                :
                <span>
                  {todo.title}
                  <button onClick={this.displayEdit}>Edit</button>
                </span>
              }
            </li>)
        })}
      </ul>    
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You use the same `this.state.showTextAreaEdit` for all elements. You need to make it unique, so that one button corresponds to one textarea.

Answer (score 0):

The state you are maintaining is not enough for that. You've to maintain every list item's state then. You can take a key like this in every item of your list

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: '...'
  isEditable: false
}
```

Now when you click in an edit button, make only that item `isEditable: true`, and then render the `textarea` based on every items `isEditable` key rather than central `showTextAreaEdit` key.